# Not able to get private go module while having port number in url

Tags: go, go-modules

#### What version of Go are you using (`go version`)?

```
go1.14 windows/amd64
```

#### Does this issue reproduce with the latest release?

Yes

#### What did you do?

$ go get -u bitbucket.mycompany.com:8443/test/go-lib

#### What did you expect to see?

download the go-lib library

#### What did you see instead?

invalid char ':'

Comment: go get downloads and installs packages, specified by import path. [Import paths are not URLs](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Import_path_syntax).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I created a reverse proxy project in go and resoved it.

In the go.mod, you have to put your reverve proxy URL without port number

Answer (score 3):

The proper go get URL would be:

```
go get -u bitbucket.mycompany.com/test/go-lib
```

But try and set with Git:

```
git config --global url."https://bitbucket.mycompany.com:8443/".insteadOf https://bitbucket.mycompany.com/
```

Comment: doesn't work for me, :443 connectex: A coonection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly response after a period of time.